# widget update button values in main application

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget with **3 different buttons** that holds some values i get from my database.

When the database is updated in the main application, i need the buttons in the widget to **get the updated values from my database** and then display them.

I would like to call an **update** on the buttons when `onStop` is called in the **main application**, but i just cant figure out how to do it.

Any suggesteons would be appreciated :)

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{ 
 //main application

    .super.onStop();
    WidgetProvider.updateMyWidgets(null, null); // does obviously not work as i dont have Context or Parcelable to send with it
    dblose();
}

public static void updateMyWidget(Context context, Parcelable data) 
{
    AppWidgetManager man = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] ids = man.getAppWidgetIds(  new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class));
    Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
    updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    updateIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON1, data);
    updateIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON2, data);
    updateIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON3, data);
    context.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    Log.w("no.reaving", "onUpdate method called");
    getTimeFromDatabase();

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    Intent active = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON1);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, active, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnTimerWidget1, actionPendingIntent);

    active = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON2);
    actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, active, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnTimerWidget2, actionPendingIntent);

    active = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON3);
    actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3, active, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnTimerWidget3, actionPendingIntent);

   // Set the text with the current time.
   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.btnTimerWidget1, TESTSTRING1 + " Hrs");
   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.btnTimerWidget2, TESTSTRING2 + " Hrs");
   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.btnTimerWidget3, TESTSTRING3 + " Hrs");

   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    WidgetProvider.context = context;
    db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    getTimeFromDatabase();

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON1)) {
        newAlarm(TESTSTRING1);
        showToast(TESTSTRING1);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON2)) {
        newAlarm(TESTSTRING2);
        showToast(TESTSTRING2);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON3)) {
        newAlarm(TESTSTRING3);
        showToast(TESTSTRING3);
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error's are you getting ?

Comment: RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity MainOpeningActivity. I just think there has to be a better way then calling on it staticly, like with a broadcast receiver as mentioned below, but i dont know how to use a broadcast receiver yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppWidgetProvider extends BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) so when the value is updated, you can send a intent to your AppWidgetProvider implementation

**Edit**
In your main application,
instead of

`WidgetProvider.updateMyWidgets(null, null);`

you send a broastcast to your `WidgetProvider` and implement the update in your `onReceive` method

See this [project](https://github.com/ccheneson/WidgetWithCount) if it can help you

Comment: Could you possibly show me a little code on how i could do that? I have yet to use a BroadcastReceiver, so i dont fully understand it